# Quaternion to quaternion power is evaluated to final form only second time

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

I implement quaternion algebra this way:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_] := 
  Dot[Matrix[x], y];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[y_, Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Dot[y, Matrix[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Matrix[y] . Log[Matrix[x]]];
Matrix /: Im[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Im[x]]
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Re[x]]
Matrix /: Arg[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Arg[x]]

$Post = FullSimplify[FullSimplify[# /. i -> Matrix[( {
               {I, 0},
               {0, -I}
              } )] /. j -> Matrix[( {
              {0, 1},
              {-1, 0}
             } )] /. k -> Matrix[( {
             {0, I},
             {I, 0}
            } ) ] /. 
        f_[args1___, Matrix[mat_], args2___] :> 
         Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]]] /. 
      Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
       Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k ] /. 
    Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
     Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k &;
```

Now, imputing `i^j` produces `E^(k Pi)/2`. This is correct, but not the final form. Putting this output to the input again produces `k`, which is the desired result. So, I have to evaluate the output again to get the result. Is there way to make it evaluated automatically?

Comment: Do you know that a quaternion package is built into MMA?

Comment: @DanielHuber yes but you cannot evaluate general functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) to apply the function multiple times:

```
(* put OP's function into a new variable *)
$Post2 = FullSimplify[FullSimplify[#/. i->Matrix[({{I,0},{0,-I}})]/. j->Matrix[({{0,1},{-1,0}})]/. k->Matrix[({{0,I},{I,0}})]/. f_[args1___,Matrix[mat_],args2___]:>Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1,#,args2]&,mat]]]/. Matrix[{{a_,c_},{d_,b_}}]:>Re[a]+Im[a] i+Re[c] j+Im[c] k]/. Matrix[{{a_,c_},{d_,b_}}]:>Re[a]+Im[a] i+Re[c] j+Im[c] k&;

(* the actual post function applies this repeatedly *)
$Post = FixedPoint[$Post2,#]&;
```

Now `i^j` does indeed evaluate to `k`.

Comment: But this leads to infinite cycle for instance in `(i + 5)^(j + 1)`.

Comment: I can believe that. Maybe you need to clarify what you want to get in that case. Suppose you do not define `$Post` (so `Quit[]`) but do define `$Post2`. Then look at the first two iterates, `$Post2[(i+5)^(j+1)]` and `$Post2[$Post2[(i+5)^(j+1)]]`. What answer would you like to get in that case? Then you need to find a general rule that gives the behavior that you like. Please understand that using `$Post` is very non-standard. If you are playing with it for fun to learn, then ok, but I would never write a serious program where `$Post` does computation.

Comment: @Anixx When dealing with noncommutative stuffs you need to specify a preferred basis or to define some kind of complexity of expressions. Following the answer of @user293787, you can try `MinimalBy[NestList[$Post2, #, 10] &, LeafCount]` to pick a result with minimal leaves.

Comment: @yurie tried this, it says MinimalBy::arg1: The first argument is expected to be a list or association.

Comment: @Anixx Sorry I copied the  wrong one. It should be like `f[x_]:=MinimalBy[NestList[$Post2, x, 10], LeafCount]`. The function `NestList` is like `FixedPoint` but will nestedly apply the first argument up to 10 times, and collect the intermediate result in each apply, so to avoid the infinite loops.

Comment: @yurie what is `f[x]`? and how to use it?

Comment: @yurie this does not work either.